# Handlebars error

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've set up handlebars and it's running fine, but when I include my 'add' method and try run the render method it throws an error:

"You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined"

Not too sure why...

HTML

```
<div id="to-do-app"></div>
<input id="add-to-do-value" type="text" placeholder="Add to do">
<button id="add-to-do">Add</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="to-do-template" type="text/template">
    <ul>
        {{#this}}
        <div>
            <li>{{value}}</li>
        </div>
        {{/this}}
    </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

JS

```
(function() {
    var toDo = {
        data: [],
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.toDoApp = document.getElementById('to-do-app');
            this.toDoTemplate = document.getElementById('to-do-template');
            this.addToDo = document.getElementById('add-to-do');
            this.addToDoValue = document.getElementById('add-to-do-value');
        },
        render: function() {
            this.toDoTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.toDoTemplate.innerHTML);
            this.toDoApp.innerHTML = this.toDoTemplate(this.data);
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.addToDo.addEventListener("click", this.add.bind(this));
        },
        add: function() {
            var toDoValue = this.addToDoValue.value;
            if(toDoValue) {
                var toDoObj = {
                    value: toDoValue
                }
            this.data.push(toDoObj);
            }
            this.render();
        },
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
            this.render();
        }
    }

    toDo.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `init` function you call `this.render()`.

The `render` function contains this line:

```
this.toDoTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.toDoTemplate.innerHTML);
```

So after you init the `this.toDoTemplate` will hold the reference to the compiled template and not the `script` element.

In you `add` you call `render` again, but because this time `this.toDoTemplate` holds the compiled template the `this.toDoTemplate.innerHTML` will be `undefined` and not a string and those you will get the error:

> You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined

How you solve this depends on the use-case.

On solution would be to compile the templates in your `cacheDom`:

```
 this.toDoTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('to-do-template'));
```

Another one would be to use two properties:

```
 this.toDoTemplateElement = document.getElementById('to-do-template')
```

And

```
 if( !this.toDoTemplate ) { // only compile it once and cache the compiled template
     this.toDoTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.toDoTemplateElement.innerHTML);
 }
```

Compiling the template on each time you call `render` is most likely something you don't want to do anyway.